# int object has no attribute id

Tags: python, flask

This problem occurs when I search for a book using SELECT * FROM books WHERE title=%s
If I change the search string to SELECT title, author, isbn, call_num FROM books it tells me that the str object has no attribute id. I am not sure how to proceed here please let me know where I am going wrong.

```
from app import app
from tables import Results
from db_config import mysql
from flask import Flask, redirect, url_for, render_template, request, flash

@app.route('/search_view')
def search_view():
    return render_template('search.html')
        
@app.route('/search', methods=['POST'])
def search_book():
    conn = None
    cursor = None
    try:        
        _title = request.form['inputTitle']
        # validate the received values
        if _title and request.method == 'POST':
            # save edits
            sql = "SELECT * FROM books WHERE title=%s"
            data = (_title)
            conn = mysql.connect()
            cursor = conn.cursor()
            cursor.execute(sql, data)
            row = cursor.fetchone()
            table = Results(row)
            table.border = True
            return render_template('books.html', table=table)
            
            flash('Successful search!')
            
        else:
            return 'Error while search for book'
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
    finally:
        cursor.close() 
        conn.close()    
@app.route('/')
def users():
    conn = None
    cursor = None
    try:
        conn = mysql.connect()
        cursor = conn.cursor(pymysql.cursors.DictCursor)
        cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM books")
        rows = cursor.fetchall()
        table = Results(rows)
        table.border = True
        return render_template('books.html', table=table)
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
    finally:
        cursor.close() 
        conn.close()

        
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

Answer (score -1):

The error message typically occurs when trying to access an attribute or method on an integer that doesn't exist. In this case, it seems like the error is happening when you're trying to create a `Results` object with `row` as an argument.

The problem is likely that `row` is an integer, not an object with an `id` attribute. This could be because the `fetchone()` method returns a single value (an integer), not a row object.

Here's how you can fix it:

1. Ensure that `fetchone()` returns a row object, not a single value. If the `SELECT` statement is only selecting one column, `fetchone()` will return just the value of that column, not a row object. To fix this, ensure your `SELECT` statement selects all the columns you need.
2. Make sure that `Results` is expecting the correct type of argument. If `Results` is expecting an object with an `id` attribute, you must ensure you're passing in an object, not an integer.

Here's a modified version of your `search_book()` function that might work:

```py
@app.route('/search', methods=['POST'])
def search_book():
    conn = None
    cursor = None
    try:        
        _title = request.form['inputTitle']
        # validate the received values
        if _title and request.method == 'POST':
            # save edits
            sql = "SELECT * FROM books WHERE title=%s"
            data = (_title,)
            conn = mysql.connect()
            cursor = conn.cursor()
            cursor.execute(sql, data)
            row = cursor.fetchone()
            if row is not None:
                table = Results(row)
                table.border = True
                return render_template('books.html', table=table)
            else:
                flash('No book found with that title.')
                return redirect(url_for('search_view'))
            
        else:
            return 'Error while searching for the book.'
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
    finally:
        if cursor:
            cursor.close() 
        if conn:
            conn.close()
```

In this version, I've added a check to see if the `row` is `None` before trying to create a `Results` object. This will prevent the error from occurring if no book is found with the specified title. I've also added a redirect back to the search view if no book is found.

I hope it can fix your problem.

Comment: Thanks for the help.  I tried to use the function you gave me but I still got "int object has no attribute id".  I tried   fetchall()    too just to see if that would work but then I got the error "tuple object has no attribute id"

Comment: `fetchone()` will never return an int or other scalar: it returns *"a single sequence, or None if no more rows are available"* (https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-api-mysqlcursor-fetchone.html) Even if only one column were queried (which is not the case in OP's code), the return would be a length-1 tuple.

Comment: The problem was with writing the data to the table.  Instead I did a render_template and wrote the data to the html page with {{item[0]}} etc on the html page.